# Load data local infile problems in Filemaker

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, filemaker

I've got a script to load a text file into an Amazon RDS mysql database. It needs to handle a variable number of columns from the text file and store them as JSON. Here's an example with 5 columns that get stored as JSON:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Applications/FileMaker Pro 14/containers/imports/load1.txt' INTO TABLE jdataholder (rowdatetime, @v1, @v2, @v3, @v4, @v5) SET loadno = 1, formatno = 1, jdata = JSON_OBJECT('Site', @v1, 'Nutrients', @v2, 'Dissolved_O2', @v3, 'Turbitidy', @v4, 'Nitrogen', @v5);`

local_infile is 'ON' on the server. The query works in Sequel Pro. When I try to run it in Filemaker Pro 14's (running on OS X 10.12) Execute SQL script step it doesn't work. I know the connection to the server is working because I can run other queries that don't use the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement.

The error message I get says:

> ODBC ERROR: [Actual][MySQL] Load data local infile forbidden

From other answers on SO and elsewhere it seems like the client also needs to have `local_infile` enabled. This would explain why it works on one client and not the other. I've tried to do this, but the instructions I've seen all use the terminal. I don't think Filemaker has anything like this - you can just enter SQL into a query editor and send that to a remote database. I'm not sure how or even if you can change the configuration of the client.

Does anyone know how to enable this on Filemaker? Or, is there something else I can do to make this work?

Could I avoid this if I ran the load data local infile query from a stored procedure? That was my original plan, but the documentation says that the load data infile step has to call literal strings, not variables, so I couldn't think of a way to handle a variable number of columns.

Thanks.

Comment: FileMaker uses ODBC driver to run "Execute SQL" queries. Try to open settings for ODBC driver and check if there is local_infile setting. Stored procedure could work as well, as far as I remember they are called Routines in MYSQL.

Comment: Thanks Nicolai, the ODBC driver is the same for Sequel Pro, which runs the query correctly, so I think the problem is with Filemaker. I tried using a stored procedure with the Load Data step, but apparently that's not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the FileMaker ExecuteSQL does not support this. I would suggest using a plugin that has the ability to run terminal commands, then use that plugin to perform the action in the terminal through FileMaker. There's a free plugin that has a function for that, it's called BaseElements. Below is a link to the documentation on this specific function.

https://baseelementsplugin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205350547-BE-ExecuteShellCommand

If you are trying to insert data into a MySQL table, a better way is to use FileMaker ESS (External SQL Sources), which allows you to work with MySQL, Oracle and other supported databases inside FileMaker. This includes being able to import data into the ESS ( MySQL table. You can see a pdf document on ESS below:

https://www.filemaker.com/downloads/documentation/techbrief_intro_ess.pdf

Comment: "Execute SQL" and "ExecuteSQL" are two different scripts steps in FileMaker

Comment: Thanks @jplasencia. I took your advice and used `BE_ExecuteSystemCommand`. Interestingly, it comes up with a similar problem. If I execute the commands through Filemaker, they don't work. But if I put then in a `.sh` file and run that file from Filemaker, it works fine. I still don't know what the root cause of this problem is, but this workaround is good enough.